# Array acting strange in Lua

Tags: arrays, lua

I am a noob in Lua. I have two arrays

First one:

```html
levels={
-- 1
{
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,1,0,9,0,3,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}
}
,
-- 2
{
{9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,1,9,9},
{9,9,0,9,9},
{9,9,0,9,9},
{9,9,0,9,9},
{9,9,0,9,9},
{9,9,3,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9}
}
,
-- 3
{
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,0,9,0,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,1,0,0,9,0,3,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9},
{9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9}
}
}
```

And The second I declare it like this:

```html
playingLevel=levels[1]
```

The problem is that after I change playingLevel values, the levels array also changes the same way. I want to change only playingLevel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

table values are references in lua. when you do

```
playingLevel=levels[1]
```

you are not copying the table value at `levels[1]` into `playingLevel`, you are getting a reference to the actual data at `levels[1]`, so changing an array value through `playingLevel` is essentially the same as changing the value as if you wrote `levels[1][some_index] = new_value`.

if you want a copy of the data, you will need a function that will create the copy for you. (either a shallow or deep copy depending on your use case)

so your code would look like `playingLevel = copyTable(levels[1])` instead where `copyTable` is your custom implementation of a function that knows how to create a copy of the target table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I used a function that returns the value of levels and it works now!